# File `graficx.sty' not found

Tags: graphics, errors, pdftex, packages, moderncv

I'm using LaTeX for a week now and I couldn't figure the problem is this error out, I have copied a CV template from internet and I made some changes, for sudden every time I make quick build in TeXMaker this error shows up

```
! LaTeX Error: File 'graficx.sty' not found
```

so can you please help me fix this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}'

\usepackage{graficx}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins

\firstname{Maissa}
\familyname{Ben Mahouachi}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{-----------}{-----------}
\mobile{}
\phone{}
\email{email@mmm.com}
\extrainfo{date and place of birth: 00/00/0000 y}
\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{picture.png} 
\begin{document}

\section{Education}

\cventry{2012--Present}{Bachelor of IT Management}{The University of ESSECT}{Tunisia}{}{}\cventry{2010--2012}{German course}{The secondary school of Farhat Hachad Rades}{Tunisia}{}{}
\cventry{2008--2012}{Baccalaureat of Computer Science}{The secondary school of Farhat Hachad Rades}{Tunisia}{}{}{}

\section{Bachelor Thesis}

\cvitem{Title}{\emph{Conception and realization of Web Application}}{}{}{}
\cvitem{Supervisors}{Professor Chalghoumi Sabrine \& Associate Professor Kabtani Imed}{}{}{}
\cvitem{Description}{This thesis explored the idea that web applications make the most used data in firms more simple, to
look for or searching for certain available references and competitor's filters' information. ..}{}{}{}

\section{Experience}

\subsection{Vocational}

\cventry{02/2015-05/2015}{\textsuperscript{computer technician assistant}}{\textsc{SOFIMA Filters}}{Ben Arous Tunisia}{Developed a web application of searching all filters' references (air filters, oil, fuel, gaz and hydraulic filters) that this firm makes and other competitors' too.
\newline{}\newline{}
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to look for informtion.
\item learned how to make connections.
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item how to work in team.
\item learned new programming languages like ASP.NET and \Csh{}.
\end{itemize}}{}

\section{Computer skills}

\cvitem{Basic}{\textsc{java}, Adobe Illustrator, \textsc{javascript},Photoshop}
\cvitem{Intermediate}{\textsc{vb.net}, \textsc{html}, \textsc{css}, \textsc{php}, \textsc{MySQL/PL-SQL}, \textsc{Oracle DB}, C , \Csh{}, \LaTeX, Linux, Microsoft Windows}
\cvitem{Advanced}{Computer Hardware and Support}

\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Fluent written and spoken}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{German}{Post Beginners}{Level A2}
\cvitemwithcomment{French}{Fluent written and spoken}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Arabic}{Mothertongue}{}

\section{Interests}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\cvlistdoubleitem{Programming}{Traveling}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Photography}{Sports}
\cvlistdoubleitem{High technology}{Cooking}

\end{document}
```

and here is error's details in the log file:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `graficx.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.32
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
18696 strings out of 493698
382839 string characters out of 3134700
424418 words of memory out of 3000000
21781 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
5898 words of font info for 18 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
76i,1n,60p,10373b,103s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: `\usepackage{graficx}` should be `\usepackage{graphicx}` . `ph` instead of `f`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) @HarishKumar got it.

Comment: Yes you are right, how can't I see that, but this error showed up:  "! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 97"

Comment: Hi and welcome, is this directly related to the typo? Please change the question to show up the new error.

Comment: btw, you shared with us, and the whole world an address and other personal information. If this is real data, you might want to ask our moderator team to permanently delete this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. First it is `graphicx` not `graficx`
2. `\cventry` has `7` arguments, you have given only six at some places.
3. `\cvitem` has only 3 arguments, you gave six.
4. `\Csh{}` is unknown for me, hence I have commented it.

With all these corrections, here is your code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins

\firstname{Maissa}
\familyname{Ben Mahouachi}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Golzwarder Straße, 87}{Brake, Oldenburg 26919}
\mobile{}
\phone{}
\email{Mahouachi.Mayssa@gmx.com}
\extrainfo{date and place of birth: 24/08/1993 Oldenburg Germany}
\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{picture.png}
\begin{document}

\section{Education}

\cventry{2012--Present}{Bachelor of IT Management}{The University of ESSECT}{Tunisia}{}{}{}
\cventry{2010--2012}{German course}{The secondary school of Farhat Hachad Rades}{Tunisia}{}{}{}
\cventry{2008--2012}{Baccalaureat of Computer Science}{The secondary school of Farhat Hachad Rades}{Tunisia}{}{}{}

\section{Bachelor Thesis}

\cvitem{Title}{\emph{Conception and realization of Web Application}}%{}{}{}
\cvitem{Supervisors}{Professor Chalghoumi Sabrine \& Associate Professor Kabtani Imed}%{}{}{}
\cvitem{Description}{This thesis explored the idea that web applications make the most used data in firms more simple, to
look for or searching for certain available references and competitor's filters' information. ..}%{}{}{}

\section{Experience}

\subsection{Vocational}

\cventry{02/2015-05/2015}{\textsuperscript{computer technician assistant}}{\textsc{SOFIMA Filters}}{Ben Arous Tunisia}{}{Developed a web application of searching all filters' references (air filters, oil, fuel, gaz and hydraulic filters) that this firm makes and other competitors' too.
\newline{}\newline{}
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to look for informtion.
\item learned how to make connections.
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item how to work in team.
\item learned new programming languages like ASP.NET and %\Csh{}.
\end{itemize}}{}

\section{Computer skills}

\cvitem{Basic}{\textsc{java}, Adobe Illustrator, \textsc{javascript},Photoshop}
\cvitem{Intermediate}{\textsc{vb.net}, \textsc{html}, \textsc{css}, \textsc{php}, \textsc{MySQL/PL-SQL}, \textsc{Oracle DB}, C , %\Csh{},
\LaTeX, Linux, Microsoft Windows}
\cvitem{Advanced}{Computer Hardware and Support}

\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Fluent written and spoken}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{German}{Post Beginners}{Level A2}
\cvitemwithcomment{French}{Fluent written and spoken}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Arabic}{Mothertongue}{}

\section{Interests}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\cvlistdoubleitem{Programming}{Traveling}{}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Photography}{Sports}{}
\cvlistdoubleitem{High technology}{Cooking}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a saver, \Csh{} I thought it displays "C#" in LaTex but it did not work, Thank you again i really appreciate your help and your time.

Comment: Hi @Harish Kumar, sorry to bother but why the header that contains my name, adress and other personel information is not showing anymore even the footer. Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: I found out, because of \makecvtitle :D